# infinite scroll with Mongo node express AND order by state

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sorting, infinite-scroll

my collection looks like :

```json
  {
    "state": "Finished",
    "title": "Task number 1e",
    "budget": 25000
  },
  {
    "state": "Created",
    "title": "Task number 2o",
    "with": 15000
  },
  {
    "state": "Created",
    "title": "Task number 3e",
    "with": 45000
  },
  {
    "state": "End",
    "title": "Task number 3r",
    "with": 65000
  },
  {
    "state": "Assigned",
    "title": "Task number 5v",
    "with": 95000
  },
```

I need to return all task in certain order (Created>Assigned>End) but using infinite scroll

I'm using aggregate function in mongodb

```js
    const tasks = await Task.aggregate([
        { $skip: (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize },
        { $limit: pageSize },
        {
            $addFields: {
                order: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $eq: ['$state', 'Created'] },
                        then: 1,
                        else: {
                            $cond: {
                                if: { $eq: ['$state', 'Assigned'] },
                                then: 2,
                                else: 3,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        { $sort: { order: 1 } },
    ]);
```

My problem is:  the results are ordering each page, but I need to order first all documents and then return sorted results page by page (remember infinite scroll), someone has any clue? For ex: first 4 pages all Created task, second 2 pages Assigned and last pages End tasks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html?searchProperty=current&query=ne#group-aggregation) stage to group documents base the "state" field.

**Stages:**

1. Exclude documents with state = "Finished".
2. Skip X amount of documents.
3. Limit the amount of documents.
4. [Group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) the documents by the state, and add task key, which is an array of documents.
5. Add a sort key, base on the _id key.
6. Perform an ascending sort operation.

Note: This operation will return 3 document that each can not exceed the maximum BSON document size ([16 megabytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size)).

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "state": {
        $ne: "Finished"
      }
    }
  },
  { $skip: (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize },
  { $limit: pageSize },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$state",
      "tasks": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sort": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$_id",
              "Created"
            ]
          },
          then: 1,
          else: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  "$_id",
                  "Assigned"
                ]
              },
              then: 2,
              else: 3
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sort: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank @haniel baez, One Q, my collection already have _id and your code is creating conflict, can you help me to use one different prop _id... I try creating another group by but doesn't work :(

Comment: All documents must have _id, but it should not be a problem. What is the error you are getting? Could you add more information about you collection?